# how to replace hardcoded number with variable in java - mysql code

Tags: java, mysql

how can i replace hardcoded number with variable in this java statement which is accessing the mysql datatabase using jdbc. the query is executed using executeQuery(query)

here is the java statement

```
String query = "select * from TableA where num = '1233' ";
```

i need to replace this 1233 with a variable in this statement.

any help appreciated

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use prepared statement, you'll be safer (no risk of SQL injection):

```
    Connection con = getMyConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from TableA where num = ?");
        try {
            ps.setLong(1, number);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                //TODO
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
        }
    } finally {
        con.close();
    }
```

Comment: @OP: Using a `PreparedStatement` like this solves a number of issues for you (escaping special characters in strings, formatting timestamps correctly, etc.), definitely the way to go. Also, you can re-use `PreparedStatement` instances if you need to (in a loop, for instance).

Comment: In addition to being safer, the driver or the pool implementation may use a query cache that improves performance.

Comment: what if the statement is not executeQuery(query)
but executeUpdate(query)
example
query = " create view view1 as select * from table where num = '1233'";

Comment: Same thing. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Hibernate`? If yes this is how you should go supose str is the string/integer you want to replace then get the str by requestobject and continue by using the following code.

```
try {
SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionfactory.openSession();<br>
String query = "from Contact c where name='"+str+"'";
Query query1 = session.createQuery(query);<br>
list = query1.list();
System.out.println("Number of users in the system :- "+list.size());
for (Contact contact : list) {
System.out.println(contact.getId()+" : "+contact.getName()+" : "+ contact.getRole()+ " : "+ contact.isEnable());
}
```

Comment: Even with Hibernate, you should use query parameters. In Hibernate it's achieved via the `org.hibernate.Query`'s `set*` methods, which is later translated by Hibernate to a `PreparedStatement`. See Jerome's answer for all the reasons why.